# System crashing thinkpad L490

Tags: crash

My thinkpad l490 is randomly crashing and shows me what's in the attached picture. Could anybody tell me what's going on? Thank you very much.

It says:
[ 290.834422] EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1ps)....

Unfortunately I'm not able to post pictures. 
https://photos.app.goo.gl/sGyKssyKtGe3QuSa6

Comment: Did you update your NVMe SSD Firmware lately? I did it over ubuntu update and have the same problem. (If found only the Windows Version, but this was the update i think https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/de/en/downloads/ds119265)

Comment: I'm not sure, but yes I did an update via ubuntu update. Did you find a solution? I took my laptop to a shop and they reinstalled Windows 10 from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having my laptop restored with Windows 10 I used it as is for a couple of days and everything was fine. They checked the hardware and couldn't finde any defects. So after a couple of days I downloaden Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and installed it but the problems persisted ant the system was crashing within a few minutes. After researching a little bit more, I read somewhere i should update BIOS. So restored again to Windows 10 and did all the available updates even the BIOS. This AM I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I'm using it for a couple hours now and no more crashes! Hopefully this was it!